# Timer example using timer.Reset() not working as described

Tags: go, timer, channel, routines

I've been working with examples trying to get my first "go routine" running and while I got it running, it won't work as prescribed by the go documentation with the timer.Reset() function.

In my case I believe that the way I am doing it is just fine because I don't actually care what's in the chan buffer, if anything. All as this is meant to do is trigger `case <-tmr.C:` if anything happened on `case _, ok := <-watcher.Events:` and then all goes quiet for at least one second. The reason for this is that `case _, ok := <-watcher.Events:` can get from one to dozens of events microseconds apart and I only care once they are all done and things have settled down again.

However I'm concerned that doing it the way that the documentation says you "must do" doesn't work. If I knew go better I would say the documentation is flawed because it assumes there is something in the buffer when there may not be but I don't know go well enough to have confidence in making that determination so I'm hoping some experts out there can enlighten me.

Below is the code. I haven't put this up on playground because I would have to do some cleaning up (remove calls to other parts of the program) and I'm not sure how I would make it react to filesystem changes for showing it working.

I've clearly marked in the code which alternative works and which doesn't.

```
func (pm *PluginManager) LoadAndWatchPlugins() error {

  // DOING OTHER STUFF HERE

    fmt.Println(`m1`)

    done := make(chan interface{})
    terminated := make(chan interface{})

    go pm.watchDir(done, terminated, nil)
    fmt.Println(`m2.pre-10`)

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println(`m3-post-10`)

    go pm.cancelWatchDir(done)
    fmt.Println(`m4`)

    <-terminated
    fmt.Println(`m5`)

    os.Exit(0) // Temporary for testing

    return Err
}

func (pm *PluginManager) cancelWatchDir(done chan interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(`t1`)

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(`t2`)

    close(done)
}

func (pm *PluginManager) watchDir(done <-chan interface{}, terminated chan interface{}, strings <-chan string) {

  watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        Logger("watchDir::"+err.Error(), `plugins`, Error)
    }

    //err = watcher.Add(pm.pluginDir)
    err = watcher.Add(`/srv/plugins/`)
    if err != nil {
        Logger("watchDir::"+err.Error(), `plugins`, Error)
    }

    var tmr = time.NewTimer(time.Second)
    tmr.Stop()

    defer close(terminated)
    defer watcher.Close()
    defer tmr.Stop()
    for {
        select {
        case <-tmr.C:
            fmt.Println(`UPDATE FIRED`)
            tmr.Stop()

        case _, ok := <-watcher.Events:
            if !ok {
                return
            }

            fmt.Println(`Ticker: STOP`)
            /*
             *  START OF ALTERNATIVES
             *
             *  THIS IS BY EXAMPLE AND STATED THAT IT "MUST BE" AT:
             *      https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Reset
             *
             *  BUT DOESN'T WORK
             */
            if !tmr.Stop() {
                fmt.Println(`Ticker: CHAN DRAIN`)
                <-tmr.C // STOPS HERE AND GOES NO FURTHER
            }
            /*
             *  BUT IF I JUST DO THIS IT WORKS
             */
            tmr.Stop()
            /*
             *  END OF ALTERNATIVES
             */

            fmt.Println(`Ticker: RESET`)
            tmr.Reset(time.Second)

        case <-done:
            fmt.Println(`DONE TRIGGERED`)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides what [icza said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58621509/1256452) (q.v.), note that the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Stop) says:

> For example, assuming the program has not received from t.C already:
>
> ```
> if !t.Stop() {
>         <-t.C
> }
> ```
>
> This cannot be done concurrent to other receives from the Timer's channel.

One could argue that this is not a great example since it assumes that the timer was running at the time you called `t.Stop`.  But it does go on to mention that this is a *bad* idea if there's already some existing goroutine that is or may be reading from `t.C`.

(The `Reset` documentation repeats all of this, and kind of in the wrong order because `Reset` sorts before `Stop`.)

Essentially, the whole area is a bit [fraught](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fraught).  There's no good general answer, because there are at least three possible situations during the return from `t.Stop` back to your call:

- No one is listening to the channel, and no timer-tick is in the channel now.  This is often the case if the timer was already stopped *before* the call to `t.Stop`.  If the timer was already stopped, `t.Stop` always returns false.
- No one is listening to the channel, and a timer-tick is in the channel now.  This is always the case when the timer was running but `t.Stop` was unable to stop it from firing.  In this case, `t.Stop` returns false.  It's also the case when the timer *was* running but fired *before* you even called `t.Stop`, and had therefore stopped on its own, so that `t.Stop` was not able to stop it and returned false.
- Someone else is listening to the channel.

In the last situation, you should do nothing.  In the first situation, you should do nothing.  In the second situation, you probably want to receive from the channel so as to clear it out.  That's what their example is for.

One could argue that:

```
if !t.Stop() {
        select {
        case <-t.C:
        default:
        }
}
```

is a better example.  It does one non-blocking attempt that will consume the timer-tick if present, and does nothing if there is no timer-tick.  This works whether or not the timer was not actually running when you called `t.Stop`.  Indeed, it even works if `t.Stop` returns `true`, though in that case, `t.Stop` stopped the timer, so the timer never managed to put a timer-tick into the channel.  (Thus, if there is a datum in the channel, it must necessarily be left over from a previous failure to clear the channel.  If there are no such bugs, the attempt to receive was in turn unnecessary.)

But, if *someone else*—some other goroutine—is or may be reading the channel, you should not do any of this at all.  There is no way to know who (you or them) will get any timer tick that might be in the channel despite the call to `Stop`.

Meanwhile, if you're *not* going to use the timer any further, it's relatively harmless just to leave a timer-tick, if there is one, in the channel.  It will be garbage-collected when the channel itself is garbage-collected.  Of course, whether this is sensible depends on what you are doing with the timer, but in these cases it suffices to just call `t.Stop` and ignore its return value.

Comment: what if a go routine is listening on a timer channel and another go routine calls Reset() on the same timer even before the expiry of the timer? Is it some kind of violation ?

Comment: @Debashish: because channels are synchronization points, and `t.C` has one buffer entry, there are limited possibilities: either there *is* one tick in the channel, or there is none; either someone—some Go routine; I like to think of them as people, or gophers—*is* blocked in a receive, if is not; when you call `t.Stop`, either the goroutine that's sending ticks (which is a system goroutine) has started its send, or has not.

Comment: So: suppose goroutine A is *blocked* on a receive (`<-t.C`), and no tick is in the channel now. Some other goroutine B—it must be some other one; A is blocked in receive—calls `t.Stop()`. Let's call the system's goroutine, that will send a tick if we don't stop it first, S. There are two cases: S has not and won't put a tick in `t.C` when B calls `t.Stop()`, or, S has-or-will put a tick in `t.C`. If S *won't* put a tick when B calls `t.Stop()`, A is now stuck, because no tick will show up.

Comment: While B can try to compensate for this, it's probably better to just write A in such a way that it won't get stuck: i.e., that it has a *conditional* receive, with a `select`.

Comment: @torek, for example a running timer `t` has spent `2 sec` of total `5 seconds` in a separate go routine and it is blocking in `t.C` channel ; and I call `t.Reset(10 sec)` from a different go routine. Will this cause `t.C` to unblock after `12 seconds ?`

Comment: Let's assign names to the goroutines, to make it easy to talk about them. Goroutine A is in `<-t.C` and has been that way for 2 seconds. Goroutine B now calls `t.Reset(10*time.Second)`. Goroutine S (which is going to send a tick in 3 more seconds) *hasn't* tried to send a tick yet; B changes the remaining time to 10 seconds; so S will now eventually send a tick in 10 seconds. A will now wake up some time after a total of approximately 12 seconds, yes.

Comment: This kind of code is generally tricky though. What if A has been waiting for *5* seconds, not 2, and S *has* started and *is* in the process of sending a tick, when B calls `t.Reset(10)`? S will send another tick in 10 seconds. We can't tell what will happen then without knowing the rest of the code for A and B.

Comment: Actually I got this situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60466530/timer-reset-in-separate-go-routine and I found OP's question related. In the above case you mentioned about the duplicate tick received in A. It is OK in my case.

Comment: surprising how hard I had to dig for a sensible explanation of one of golangs most basic library functions. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You create a timer and you stop it immediately:

```
var tmr = time.NewTimer(time.Second)
tmr.Stop()
```

This doesn't make any sense, I assume this is just an "accident" from your part.

But going further, inside your loop:

```
    case _, ok := <-watcher.Events:
```

When this happens, you claim this doesn't work:

```
        if !tmr.Stop() {
            fmt.Println(`Ticker: CHAN DRAIN`)
            <-tmr.C // STOPS HERE AND GOES NO FURTHER
        }
```

[`Timer.Stop()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Stop) documents that it returns `true` if this call stops the timer, and `false` if the timer has already been stopped (or expired). But your timer was already stopped, right after its creation, so `tmr.Stop()` returns `false` properly, so you go inside the `if` and try to receive from `tmr.C`, but since the timer was "long" stopped, nothing will be sent on its channel, so this is a blocking (forever) operation.

If you're the one stopping the timer explicitly with `timer.Stop()`, the recommended "pattern" to drain its channel doesn't make any sense and doesn't work for the 2nd `Timer.Stop()` call.

Comment: It wasn't an accident to stop the timer immediately. I would have preferred to create it but not yet start it ticking so that it only started ticking upon an event from the other channel but I didn't know how to do that. If I just set the var to the type *Timer instead of starting the timer then the select gets stuck so I had to get the timer started and then immediately stop it.