# timer reset in separate go routine

Tags: go, timer

In the following scenario a network entity always waits for a `TimeOutTime` seconds before doing a particular task `X`. Assume this time as `TimerT`. During this wait of `TimeOutTime` seconds if the entity receives a set of external messages, it should reset the same `TimerT` to `TimeOutTime` again. If no external messages are received the expected behaviour is as follows:

1. Timer Expired
2. Do task X
3. Reset the Timer again to `TimeOutTime`

(by `reset` I mean, stop the timer and start over again)

[image]

To simulate the scenario I wrote the following code in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const TimeOutTime = 3
const MeanArrivalTime = 4

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    t := time.NewTimer(time.Second * time.Duration(TimeOutTime))
    wg.Add(1)
    // go routine for doing timeout event
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            t1 := time.Now()
            <-t.C
            t2 := time.Now()
            // Do.. task X .. on timeout...
            log.Println("Timeout after ", t2.Sub(t1))
            t.Reset(time.Second * time.Duration(TimeOutTime))
        }
    }()

    // go routine to simulate incoming messages ...
    // second go routine
    go func() {
        for {
            // simulates a incoming message at any time
            time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(rand.Intn(MeanArrivalTime)))

            // once any message is received reset the timer to TimeOutTime seconds again
            t.Reset(time.Second * time.Duration(TimeOutTime))
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

After running this program using `-race` flag it shows `DATA_RACE`:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c0000c2068 by goroutine 8:
  time.(*Timer).Reset()
      /usr/local/go/src/time/sleep.go:125 +0x98
  main.main.func1()
      /home/deka/Academic/go/src/main/test.go:29 +0x18f

Previous write at 0x00c0000c2068 by goroutine 9:
  time.(*Timer).Reset()
      /usr/local/go/src/time/sleep.go:125 +0x98
  main.main.func2()
      /home/deka/Academic/go/src/main/test.go:42 +0x80

Goroutine 8 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/deka/Academic/go/src/main/test.go:20 +0x1d3

Goroutine 9 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/deka/Academic/go/src/main/test.go:35 +0x1f5
==================
```

Then I used a Mutex to wrap the `Reset()` call inside the Mutex.

package main

```
import (
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const TimeOutTime = 3
const MeanArrivalTime = 4

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    t := time.NewTimer(time.Second * time.Duration(TimeOutTime))
    wg.Add(1)
    var mu sync.Mutex
    // go routine for doing timeout event
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            t1 := time.Now()
            <-t.C
            t2 := time.Now()
            // Do.. task X .. on timeout...
            log.Println("Timeout after ", t2.Sub(t1))
            mu.Lock()
            t.Reset(time.Second * time.Duration(TimeOutTime))
            mu.Unlock()
        }
    }()

    // go routine to simulate incoming messages ...
    // second go routine
    go func() {
        for {
            // simulates a incoming message at any time
            time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(rand.Intn(MeanArrivalTime)))

            // once any message is received reset the timer to TimeOutTime seconds again
            mu.Lock()
            t.Reset(time.Second * time.Duration(TimeOutTime))
            mu.Unlock()
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

After this code seems to work fine based on the following observation.

If I replace the line

`time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(rand.Intn(MeanArrivalTime)))`

in the second go routine with a constant time of sleep of `4 seconds` and the `TimeOutTime` is constant at `3 seconds`.

Output of the program is:

```
2020/02/29 20:10:11 Timeout after  3.000160828s
2020/02/29 20:10:15 Timeout after  4.000444017s
2020/02/29 20:10:19 Timeout after  4.000454657s
2020/02/29 20:10:23 Timeout after  4.000304877s
```

In the above execution, `2nd` go routine is resetting the `active timer` after the timer has spent initial one second. Because of which, the `timer` is getting expired after `4` seconds from the second print onward.

Now when I checked the documentation of `Reset()` I found the following:

```
// Copyright 2009 The Go Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style
// license that can be found in the LICENSE file.



// Reset changes the timer to expire after duration d.
// It returns true if the timer had been active, false if the timer had
// expired or been stopped.
//
// Reset should be invoked only on stopped or expired timers with drained channels.
// If a program has already received a value from t.C, the timer is known
// to have expired and the channel drained, so t.Reset can be used directly.
// If a program has not yet received a value from t.C, however,
// the timer must be stopped and—if Stop reports that the timer expired
// before being stopped—the channel explicitly drained:
//
//  if !t.Stop() {
//      <-t.C
//  }
//  t.Reset(d)
//
// This should not be done concurrent to other receives from the Timer's
// channel.
//
// Note that it is not possible to use Reset's return value correctly, as there
// is a race condition between draining the channel and the new timer expiring.
// Reset should always be invoked on stopped or expired channels, as described above.
// The return value exists to preserve compatibility with existing programs.
```

I found this diagram: (link : https://blogtitle.github.io/go-advanced-concurrency-patterns-part-2-timers/)

[image: Time Diagram GoLang]

With the digram in mind, it seems that I need to use,

```
if !t.Stop() {
    <-t.C
}
t.Reset(d)
```

in the `2nd` go routine. In this case I also need to do proper locking in both the go routine to avoid infinite wait on channel.

I don't understand the scenario under which the `t.Stop() + draining of the channel (<-t.C)` should be performed. In which case it is required ? In my example I don't use channel read values.  Can I call Reset() without calling Stop() ?

Comment: What do you hope to observe with the simulation? And why does the message sending goroutine have to share state (namely the timer) with the worker goroutine?

Comment: @ShangjianDing when a particular message arrives, the timer has to be started over again.

Comment: How about this: https://play.golang.org/p/imlHZ5Vhzwo

Comment: @ShangjianDing your solution does consider resetting timer. And my situation is not related to producer consumer semantic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simplified the code using `time.After` function:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

const TimeOutTime = 3
const MeanArrivalTime = 4

func main() {
    const interval = time.Second * TimeOutTime
    // channel for incoming messages
    var incomeCh = make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        for {
            // On each iteration new timer is created
            select {
            case <-time.After(interval):
                time.Sleep(time.Second)
                log.Println("Do task")
            case <-incomeCh:
                log.Println("Handle income message and move to the next iteration")
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(MeanArrivalTime)) * time.Second)
            // generate incoming message
            incomeCh <- struct{}{}
        }
    }()

    // prevent main to stop for a while
    <-time.After(10 * time.Second)
}
```

Note that:

> `After` waits for the duration to elapse and then sends the current time
>   on the returned channel.
>   It is equivalent to `NewTimer(d).C`.
>   The underlying Timer is not recovered by the garbage collector
>   until the timer fires. If efficiency is a concern, use `NewTimer`
>   instead and call `Timer.Stop` if the timer is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean this while using NewTimer ? https://play.golang.org/p/XCj-Ab_7K76

Comment: Yes, it should work. According to the documentation, to ensure the channel is empty after a call to Stop, check the return value and drain the channel. For example, assuming the program has not received from `t.C` already: `if !t.Stop() {<-t.C}`

Comment: This one would be correct https://play.golang.org/p/00_3b17k9LO

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have:

```
t.Stop()
t.Reset()
```

If the timer is stopped and drained before calling `Stop`, this works fine. The problem manifests itself if `Stop` stops the timer and timer ticks at the same time. Then you may end up with a stopped timer with a goroutine waiting to write to the `t.C` channel. So `Stop` returns false if there is still a goroutine waiting to write to `t.C`, and you have to read from it. Otherwise, you'll have that goroutine waiting there indefinitely.

So, as you already observed, you have to do:

```
if !t.Stop() {
    <-t.C
}
t.Reset(d)
```

However, even with that, I think your solution is flawed because of the use of asynchronous resets. Instead, try using a new timer for each simulated event.

Comment: Hi, Can I call Reset()  without executing Stop() ?

Comment: okay. What if I call Reset() in one go routine while timer is running in other go routine? Like I showed in the second code example. Both go routine is doing Reset() using locks. And It is OK to reset the timer consecutively in short succession by two go routine in my case.

Comment: Looking at your code more carefully, I think you should consider implementing your simulation in another way. By stopping/resetting a shared timer asynchronously you're violating the timer contract.

Comment: I think your solution is flawed. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a different overall design.

Suppose for instance that we write a routine or interface called Deadliner—it could become its own package if you like, or just be an interface, and we'll see a pretty strong resemblance to something Go already has—whose job / contract is described this way:

- The user of a Deadliner creates a Deadline whenever they like.
- The Deadliner waits until the deadline occurs, then flags the deadline as having occurred.
- A Deadliner can be canceled by any Go routine any time.  This flags the deadliner as canceled, so that anyone waiting on it will stop waiting, and can tell that the reason they stopped waiting was "canceled" (not "expired").  It helps clean up resources for gc as well, in case you create a lot of Deadliners and then discard them before their timeout fires.

Now in your top level, before you start waiting for a message, you simply set up a deadline.  This isn't a timer (even if it may use one internally), it's just a Deadliner instance.  Then you wait for one of two events:

```
d, cancel = newDeadline(when)
for {
    select {
    case <-d.Done():
          // Deadline expired.
          // ... handle it ...
          d, cancel = newDeadline(when) // if/as appropriate
    case m := <-msgC:
          // got message - cancel existing deadline and get new one
          cancel()
          d, cancel = newDeadline(when)
          // ... handle the message
    }
}
```

Now we just note that Go already has this: it's in package `context`.  `d` is a context; `newDeadline` is `context.WithDeadline` or `context.WithTimeout` (depending on whether you want to compute the deadline time yourself, or have the timeout code add a duration to "now").

There is no need to fiddle with timers and time-tick channels and no need to spin off your own separate goroutines.

If the deadline doesn't reset on a single message, but rather on a particular combination of messages, you just write that in your `case <-msgChan` section.  If messages aren't currently received via channels, make that happen by putting messages into a channel, so that you can use this very simple wait-for-deadline-or-message pattern.

Comment: is there any memory leak issue with previous contexts ?

Comment: Not as long as you update your variables to remember the new context instead of the old one. (If you have a call chain in which the first context is remembered, that will keep the first context alive, but that's just one context, not an ever growing list of them.)

Comment: does calling cancel() trigger actually the <-d.Done() case? I would assume that it noramlly would trigger also the Done case, but as we reassign the context just after, the switch case will not read the done channel from the first ctx, but only from the newly created one. Is calling cancel necessary to kill the timeout timer of the first ctx, so the garbage collector can colelct it? would it leak otherwise until timeout expires?

Comment: @simon: the [context documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithDeadline) provides your answers.

Comment: 1) yes it does not call the Done() function right after, as context was reassigned
2) GC can collect canceled or expired contexts